# Code deploy throws error Family can not be blank

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, cicd, aws-code-deploy

I am currently trying to use code pipeline to perform an ecs blue green deployment. I have a task definition that is defined like this:

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: "Project-Grafana-task"
      Cpu: 512
      Memory: 1024
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref Role
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ExecutionRole.Arn
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
        - EC2
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: Grafana
          Image: grafana/grafana
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 3000
          MountPoints:
            - SourceVolume: Grafana-home
              ContainerPath: /var/Grafana_home
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref CloudwatchLogsGroup
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-stream-prefix: Grafana
      Volumes:
        - Name: Grafana-home
          EFSVolumeConfiguration:
            FilesystemId: !GetAtt TaskNetworking.Outputs.FileSystemID
            TransitEncryption: ENABLED
            AuthorizationConfig:
              AccessPointId: !GetAtt TaskNetworking.Outputs.AccessPointId
              IAM: ENABLED
```

And a taskdef.json file that looks like:

```
{
    "Family":"Project-Grafana-task",
    "Cpu": 512,
    "Memory": 1024,
    "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
    "TaskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/grafana-role",
    "ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/grafana-execution-role",
    "RequiresCompatibilities": [
      "FARGATE",
      "EC2"
    ],
    "ContainerDefinitions": [
      {
        "Name": "Grafana",
        "Image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>",
        "PortMappings": [
          {
            "ContainerPort": 3000
          }
        ],
        "MountPoints": [
          {
            "SourceVolume": "Grafana-home",
            "ContainerPath": "/var/Grafana_home"
          }
        ],
        "LogConfiguration": {
          "LogDriver": "awslogs",
          "Options": {
            "awslogs-group": "CloudwatchLogsGroup",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "Grafana"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Volumes": [
      {
        "Name": "Grafana-home",
        "EFSVolumeConfiguration": {
          "FilesystemId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "TransitEncryption": "ENABLED",
          "AuthorizationConfig": {
            "AccessPointId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "IAM": "ENABLED"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

When trying to run the pipeline this returns the error:

```
Family can not be blank.
```

Have I missed a place where family can be defined, my current understanding is that if the taskdef.json and the appspec.json (which is also included) get passed to the code deploy part of the pipe line I should get a blue/green deployment. Also worth noting the code deploy job is already set up as well.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Comment: @Nonik , yea but I thought I did that already in my task defemination

Comment: yes, take a look , amazon properties need to be like this"lowercaseUpperCase" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html#example_task_definition-iam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taskdef.json needs the keys to be  camel case so Family needs to be family and  MountPoints would need to be mountPoints